# Automapper. How to map custom type property of inner class (source) to string and string array?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map source inner classes to string and in other case string array but in both cases they are mapped to null. I want MapNoteFromInnerSourceEntity1 to hold a value of InnerSourceEntity1 Id property and MapValueFromInnerSourceEntity2 to hold values of InnerSourceEntity2 value properties. So far automapper is quite difficult for me to understand.

Code:

```
    internal class Program
{
    public class InnerSourceEntity1
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerSourceEntity2
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceEntity
    {
        public InnerSourceEntity1 A { get; set; }
        public IList<InnerSourceEntity2> B { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationEntity
    {
        public string MapNoteFromInnerSourceEntity1 { get; set; }
        public string[] MapValueFromInnerSourceEntity2 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var source = new SourceEntity
        {
            A = new InnerSourceEntity1 { Note = "Note", Id = "Id"},
            B = new List<InnerSourceEntity2> { new InnerSourceEntity2 { Id = "Id", Value = "Value" }, new InnerSourceEntity2 { Id = "Id", Value = "Value" } }
        };

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>();
            cfg.CreateMap<InnerSourceEntity1, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s.Note);
            cfg.CreateMap<IList<InnerSourceEntity2>, string[]>();
        });

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        DestinationEntity destination = mapper.Map<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>(source);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: I read the documentation but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since the names of properties between source type `SourceEntity` and destination type `DestinationEntity` don't match, you'll have to explicitly indicate them, otherwise AutoMapper will not know how to fill the properties:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>()
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.MapNoteFromInnerSourceEntity1,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.A))
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.MapValueFromInnerSourceEntity2,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.B));
```

Also, don't map between concrete collection types:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IList<InnerSourceEntity2>, string[]>(); // <== Don't do that.
```

Instead, see what the docs say about mapping collections:

> (...) it’s not necessary to explicitly configure list types, only their member types. ~ [AutoMapper Docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html#lists-and-arrays)

So, you only need to specify map like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<InnerSourceEntity2, string>();
```

And since we are mapping to `string` we also need to instruct the AutoMapper from where it can get the `string` value. So, we'll use `ConvertUsing()` again:

```
cfg.CreateMap<InnerSourceEntity2, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s.Value);
```

Final configuration:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>()
        .ForMember(
            dst => dst.MapNoteFromInnerSourceEntity1,
            opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.A))
        .ForMember(
            dst => dst.MapValueFromInnerSourceEntity2,
            opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.B));
    cfg.CreateMap<InnerSourceEntity1, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s.Note);
    cfg.CreateMap<InnerSourceEntity2, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s.Value);
});
```